# Scipy CSR Matrix Element-wise Addition

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Unlike numpy arrays/matrices, CSR matrix seems not to allow automatic broadcasting. There are methods in the CSR implementation for element-wise multiplication, but not addition. How to add to a CSR Sparse matrix by a scalar efficiently?

Comment: I answered something similar in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048431/how-to-add-a-sparse-row-to-a-sparse-matrix-in-python - adding a row.   After adding a scalar the matrix no longer is sparse; multiplication by a scalar preserves the sparsity (no new nonzero elements).

Comment: makes sense. the addition should be such that it updates also the integer (generally 0) that denotes sparsity. a method on csr matrix should have been there that takes care all these internally.

Comment: There's no such variable.  The roots of this package are in linear algebra.  An offset would be removed the linear equation algebraically before this.  Panadas sparse format does allow for a nonzero `fill` (e.g. `nan`).

Comment: The assumption that the `fill` value is zero permeates the calculation methods.  Multiplications in particular assume that if the element value from either argument is zero the product is zero, so it can take shortcuts.  It only has to work with the non-zero values.  There's more to `sparse` than simply saving data storage requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we want to add a scalar to the non-zero entries and leave alone the matrix
sparseness, i.e. do not touch the zero entries.

---

From the [fine Scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) (`** emphasis **` is mine):

> ```
> Attributes
>
> nnz                   Get the count of explicitly-stored values (nonzeros)  
> has_sorted_indices    Determine whether the matrix has sorted indices  
> dtype (dtype)         Data type of the matrix  
> shape (2-tuple)       Shape of the matrix  
> ndim  (int)           Number of dimensions (this is always 2)  
> **data                CSR format data array of the matrix** 
> indices               CSR format index array of the matrix  
> indptr                CSR format index pointer array of the matrix
> ```

So I tried (the first part is "stolen" from the referenced documentation)

```
In [18]: from scipy import *

In [19]: from scipy.sparse import *

In [20]: row = array([0,0,1,2,2,2])
    ...: col = array([0,2,2,0,1,2])
    ...: data =array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    ...: a = csr_matrix( (data,(row,col)), shape=(3,3))
    ...: 

In [21]: a.todense()
Out[21]: 
matrix([[1, 0, 2],
        [0, 0, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int64)

In [22]: a.data += 10

In [23]: a.todense()
Out[23]: 
matrix([[11,  0, 12],
        [ 0,  0, 13],
        [14, 15, 16]], dtype=int64)

In [24]:
```

It works.  Should you save the original matrix you can use the constructor
using a modified data array.

---

***Disclaimer***

This answer addresses this **interpretation** of the question

> I have a sparse matrix, I want to add a scalar to the non zero entries, preserving the *sparseness* both of the matrix and of its programmatic representation.

My reasoning for choosing this interpretation is that adding a scalar to *all* entries turns the sparse matrix in a VERY dense matrix...

If this is the correct interpretation, I don't know: on one hand the OP approved my answer (at least today 2017-07-13) on the other hand in the comments beneath their question it seems they has of a different opinion.

The answer is however useful in the use case that the sparse matrix represents, e.g., sparse measurements and you want to correct a measurement bias, subtract a mean value, etc. so I'm going to leave it here, even if it can be judged controversial.